# Remove first and last characters

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

A Field gives me the following string:

> #$Mercury#$Venus#$Earth#$Mars#$

My goal is to remove the #$-chars and separate the text with comma and space. It should look like this:

> Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars

What I tried to do:

1. Remove the #$-chars at start and end;
2. Replace the remaining #$-chars with ", "

My code:

```
=Replace(
        Left(
            Right(
                First(Fields!FieldX.Value, "DATASET"), Len(First(Fields!FieldX.Value, "DATASET"))-2),
            Len(First(Fields!FieldX.Value, "DATASET"))-2),
        "#$",", "
        )
```

This gives me:

> Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars,

At the end after Mars there is a comma and it shouldn't be there. I don't know how to do that. Maybe the MID function is the better solution, but then I don't understand how it can be used when the strings are of variable length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I tested in a table so you will have to add the `FIRST` and `"DATASET"` bits back in )

```
=JOIN(
    SPLIT(MID(Fields!SampleText.Value, 3, LEN(Fields!SampleText.Value)-4), "#$"),
    ",")
```

All we do here is chop off the first and last 2 characters, then `SPLIT` on each instance of `#S` which gives us an array. Then `JOIN` the array elements back togther using `,` as the delimiter.

[image]